# Child window created by CreateEx() overlapped by sibling windows

Tags: c++, mfc, window

I tried to create a child window using:

```
CreateWindowEx( NULL, NULL, "MyChild", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 300, 300, 400, 200, hParentWnd, NULL, NULL );
```

where the parent HWND hParentWnd has many other child windows already.  However, this created a child window hiding behind all the siblings.  Windows Spy++ shows that it is on top (first) of the z-order among the child windows of hParentWnd.  I have tried all different win32 commands including `SetWindowPos()`, `BringWindowToTop()`, `SetForegroundWindow()`, `SetFocus()`, `SetActiveWindow()`, `SendMessage(WM_ACTIVATE, 0, 0)`, etc., but none brings it from behind the siblings.  When I replaced `WS_CHILD` by `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` in the `CreateWindowEx()` command, the created non-child window has no problem showing as the topmost foreground active window.  So what must I do to get the child window to the top from behind the siblings?

Thanks a million.

z/0

Comment: SetWindowPos() should bring the window to the front, when invoked properly. If it didn't work, please state how you used it and what happened.

Comment: Hello Roel,

Here is the code I used:

   CWnd* pChildWnd = new CWnd;
   pChildWnd->CreateEx( NULL, NULL, "MyChild", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_VSCROLL, childRect, CWnd::FromHandle(m_hWnd), NULL, NULL );
   pChildWnd->SetWindowPos(&wndTop, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);

Windows Spy++ confirmed that the SetWindowPos() command did bring it to the top of the z-order; however, it was still behind all its siblings.

Thanks.

ec

Comment: If Spy++ says it's on top then it's really there. Did you try moving another window over your window and moving it back off, to see if it's a redrawing issue? Also, check the WS_CLIPSIBLINGS style of the other controls that are 'under' the new one.

Comment: I did add WS_CLIPSIBLINGS but it didn't make a difference.  I could drag the vertical scroll (I had WS_VSCROLL in the style), but I could not bring MyChild to the foreground.  It always remains behind all siblings.

Comment: I tried adding another button before and after creating MyChild using:         `HWND hButtWnd = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_STATICEDGE, "BUTTON", "MyButton", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, buttRect.left, buttRect.top, 50, 60, m_hWnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL );`   
`::EnableWindow(hButtWnd, FALSE);`           MyChild still hides behind MyButton and all other pre-existing siblings.        Also disabling MyButton only greyed out the button and MyChild is still hiding behind all siblings.

Comment: Try using HWND_TOPMOST instead of &wndTop in your SetWindowPos().

Comment: I changed the SetWindowPos() to use HWND_TOPMOST as you suggested to:      `::SetWindowPos(pChildWnd->GetSafeHwnd(), HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);`     but it didn't work, and instead it brought MyChild to the **bottom of the z-order** as verified by Windows Spy++.  When I replaced **HWND_TOPMOST** by **HWND_TOP**, it went back behaving just like before -- meaning MyChild is on **top of z-order** but **still behind all its siblings**.  Thanks.  Please let me know of any other ideas.

Comment: Sorry yes HWND_TOP is what I meant. One more thing you can try (then I'm out of ideas) is to call ::SetFocus() on the newly created window before doing the SetWindowPos().

Comment: One last thing is to check that the other windows don't have the HWND_TOPMOST set. Try calling SetWindowPos() on them with HWND_BOTTOM, to check if that puts them to the back.

Comment: I did      `::SetFocus(pChildWnd->GetSafeHwnd());`     as you said but has no effect.  SetWindowPos() does move MyChild to the top of z-order, but the problem is that it is still hidden behind its siblings when displayed.  Why?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite explicit in the MSDN article for CreateWindowEx():

> If the created window is a child window, its default position is at the **bottom** of the Z-order. If the created window is a top-level window, its default position is at the top of the Z-order.

You'll need to move it to the top of the Z-order with SetWindowPos().

Comment: I did use SetWindowPos() to move it to the top of the z-order as Windows Spy++ confirmed it; however, the child window after being at the top of the z-order still is hidden behind the siblings.  This is what so frustrated me.  Please advise.

Comment: I cannot see your code from here, debugging blindly is impossible.  Improve your snippet.

Comment: Hello Hans,

Here is the code I used:

   `CWnd* pChildWnd = new CWnd;`
   `pChildWnd->CreateEx( NULL, NULL, "MyChild", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_VSCROLL, childRect, CWnd::FromHandle(m_hWnd), NULL, NULL );`
   `pChildWnd->SetWindowPos(&wndTop, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);`

Windows Spy++ confirmed that the **SetWindowPos()** command did bring it to the **top** of the z-order; however, it was still **behind all its siblings**.

Thanks.

ec

Comment: I tried adding another button (before and after MyChild):              `HWND hButtWnd = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_STATICEDGE, "BUTTON", "MyButton", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, buttRect.left, buttRect.top, 50, 60, m_hWnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL ); `      
`::EnableWindow(hButtWnd, FALSE);`            After that MyChild is still behind MyButton and other pre-existing siblings.       I could not bring it to the foreground by clicking it.     Also disabling MyButton only greyed out the button, and MyChild is still behind the greyed out button.